# Facebook Android SDK to create feed dialog with privacy button

Tags: android, facebook

I am able to post facebook feed through Facebook Android SDK; however, I found that the feed dialog doesn't have privacy setting button, did I do anything wrong?

```
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("description", "This is description!");
    params.putString("name", "appname");
    params.putString("captions", "This is captions!");
    params.putString("link", "http://www.google.com");

    facebook.dialog(this, "feed", params,

              new DialogListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onComplete(Bundle values) {}

                   @Override
                   public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {}

                   @Override
                   public void onError(DialogError e) {}

                   @Override
                   public void onCancel() {}
              }
        );
```

Comment: hey ur above code helped me for fb sharing.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure privacy via params in `facebook.dialog(this, "feed",`**params**`, ...)` see [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) for details